# PDO Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Tags: php, pdo

I get this error:
 Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

```
require("gebruikersdata.php");

class Database
{
    private $con;

    public function _construct($host,$username,$password,$database)
    {
        $this->con = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$database,$username,$password);
    }

    public function getGebruiker($sql)
    {
        $statement = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        while($row = $statement->fetch())
        {
            $dataSet[] = new GebruikersData ($row);
        }
        if (!empty($dataSet))
            return $dataSet;
        else 
            return null;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you put the code from where you call "getGebruiker" this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change `_construct()` to `__construct()` (**note the double underscores**).

Otherwise it won't be called on class initialization.